# Jquery ajax in php value fetch

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to fetch value from database using jquery ajax in php. when i run and select "Development" from Product/Service  then value fetch but all fetching value are join together and joinvalue show all the fields.But I want to show different value in different field. how to solve that that problem.MY code is below. please check it and solve that problem

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>Document Data</div>
  <br />
  <p></p>
  <table width="1110" border="0" >
    <tr>
        <td>
          <font size="-1">Client: </font>
          <select name="">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="Add Client">Add New Client</option>
            <?php
            include_once('database/db.php');
            $sql = "Select * from clientdetails";
            $result = mysql_query($sql);
            while ($dtset = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {?>
              <option value="<?php echo $dtset['client_name']; ?>">
                <font size="-    1"><?php echo $dtset['client_name']; ?></font>
              </option>
            <?php }?>
          </select>  
        </td>
        <td>
          <font size="-1">Document Number:</font>
        </td>
        <td> 
          <input type="number" name="num" style="height:16px; width:34px;" required />
        </td>
        <td>
          <font size="-1">Issue Date:</font>
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="date" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <font size="-1">P.O. Number:</font>
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" name="ponum" /></td>
      <td><font size="-1">Payment terms:</font></td>
      <td>
        <select name="paymentterms">
          <option value="">Select Payment Terms</option>
          <option value="">Net45</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><font size="-1">P.O. Date: </font></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="ponum" /></td>
      <td><font size="-1">Due Date: </font></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="ponum" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table width="1112" border="0">
    <tr><td><font size="-1">Products/Services</font></td>
        <td><font size="-1">Description</font></td>
        <td><font size="-1">UoM</font></td>
        <td><font size="-1">QTY</font></td>
        <td><font size="-1">Unit Price</font></td> 
        <td><font size="-1">Discount (%) </font></td>
        <td><font size="-1">Tax</font></td>
        <td><font size="-1">Action</font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select name="Pro/serv" onChange="my_validate_func()" id="pro_serv">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="" ><font size="-1">Add New Product</font></option>
          <option value="Development"><font size="-1">Development</font></option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" name="desc" id="desc" value="" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="umo" /></td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" name="qty" style="height:16px; width:34px;" required />
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" name="unitprice" id="unitprice" value="" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="discount" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="tax" id="tax" value="" /></td>
      <td><a href="add"><img src="img/add.jpg" height="40px" width="50px" /></a></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/jquery1.8.3jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {});
    function my_validate_func() {
      var pro_serv = $('#pro_serv').val();
      if ($('#type').val() != "") {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'check.php',
            data: {pro_serv: pro_serv},
            success: function (response) {
              $('#desc').val(response);
              $('#unitprice').val(response);
              $('#tax').val(response);
            }
        });
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**check.php**

```
<?php
include('database/db.php');
$type=$_POST['pro_serv'];
$sql="Select * from product_service_details where type='$type'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
if($dtset=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $desc=$dtset['desc'];
  $unitprice=$dtset['unitprice'];
  $tax=$dtset['tax'];
  echo $desc;
  echo $unitprice;
  echo $tax;
}?>
```

Comment: Then learn what is json.

Answer (score 0):

Use **[json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)**.

Return Ajax response in JSON format.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {});
    function my_validate_func() {
      var pro_serv = $('#pro_serv').val();
      if ($('#type').val() != "") {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'check.php',
            data: {pro_serv: pro_serv},
            dataType: "json", //Newly Added
            success: function (response) {
              if(response.length != 0){ //Newly Added (Check, if array is not empty, then print the returned values to respective fields)
                $('#desc').val(response['desc']); //Modified
                $('#unitprice').val(response['unitprice']); //Modified
                $('#tax').val(response['tax']); //Modified
              }
            }
        });
      }
    }
  </script>
```

**check.php**

```
<?php
include('database/db.php');
$type=$_POST['pro_serv'];
$sql="Select * from product_service_details where type='$type'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$return_values = []; //Newly Added
if($dtset = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  /* Modified */
  $return_values = [
    'desc' => $dtset['desc'],
    'unitprice' => $dtset['unitprice'],
    'tax' => $dtset['tax']
  ];
}
return json_encode($return_values); // Return as JSON format
?>
```

Comment: In check.php, write `print_r($return_values); die;` before `return json_encode($return_values);` and check what values coming @Doni

Comment: No value :(      if i run direct check.php. show parser error in line 6

Comment: Line No 6 means $return_values = [];